Short Circuit Transconductance Cadence

Hello, I am curious about hand calculation about overall Gm by using short circuit transconductance.
I got M2 of gm is 1.176mA/V, M2 of gmb is 0.2078mA/V. It should be around 1.14mA/V by using short circuit transconductance.
However, I had simultaion of overall Gm was 2.3 mA/V. Hand calculation was two times as many as simulation.
Interestingly, when I had the hand calculation of overall Gm in second picture, I got 1.156mA/V, while I got 1.117mA/V on simulation. It was 3.4% of acceptable error.
Why there is a huge difference in first picture?
Thanks a lot
Reference: My screenshot in cadence

